# Best practice to build resources provisioning structure multi environment by Bicep in Azure

Tags: azure, github-actions, infrastructure-as-code

I'm seeing the build of project about Iac in azure, that involves several types of resource as Azure Data Factory, A Data explorer, Event hub, Function Apps, Virtual machines, IoT Hub,  A Container registry, A storage account etc.
The resources are defined by Bicep files.
The resources deploy has been done by GitHub-actions, where each workflow yml file deploys the corresponding resource.

- The current **folders structure** implemented is the followed:

  Resource Provisioning -> Bicep ->

  ```
          ADX
          ADF
          ..
          etc
  ```
- The current **resource parameters handling** for each resource is the followed:

  example for ADX resource:

  [image]

I'd like to know some opinions about the points above.

Also if there is another better structure than the current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer the Best Practices for Biceps [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-resource-manager/bicep/best-practices.md)

Some practices you can use are below:-

In your bicep files, Try to use variables for complex expressions instead of embedding the resource properties directly. This makes the bicep files and code, Easily readable. Its also recommended to use string interpolation for making your bicep files manageable.

Use the resource property output in your code, This allows the resource to output the property instead of you constructing the output property yourself.

Regarding the folder layout, it is a good idea to arrange your Bicep files according to their resource types. Finding and managing your files is simpler using this method.

Refer this [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-bicep-samples/tree/main/samples) sample for best practices and syntax for more information.

Comment: I appreciated much your answer and especially the links that you shared me. In addition  to this I found another interesting link to handle an infrastructure project multienv (DEV and PROD).
https://github.com/kevball2/bicepadvanceddeployments/tree/main